# Validation for Input form component React

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, input, react-hooks

I have a form component that include multiple TextFields and each one have different validation and error. Assume my TextField had custom validation prop that will take some conditions and show validation either onChange or onBlur for each TextField. I also have custom error prop that display message without condition.

```
const Address = ({
  onChange,
  required,
  error,
  value = {},
  validation = undefined,
}: AddressProps) => {

  const validator = {
    validationAddress: (value: string) => (value.length === 0) ?  'Address is required' : '',
    validationCity: (value: string) => (value.length === 0) ?  'City is required' : '',
  }
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    ...
  }

 return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <TextField
          id="address"
          label="address"
          type="text"
          required={required}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={value.address}
          validationEvent="change"
          validation={validator.validationAddress}
        />
        <TextField
          id="city"
          label="city"
          type="text"
          required={required}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={value.city}
          validationEvent="change"
          validation={validator.validationCity}
        />
     </React.Fragment>
export default Address;
```

After that I will implement my Address component in an App with submit button.

```
const App = () => {
   const handleSubmit = () => {
     ...
   }

   return (
     <Address />
     <button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>
         Submit
     </button>
   )
}
export default App;
```

I saw many examples that input and form put together with submit button but I am struggling with handle them separately this way. My task is need to handle validation in Address component but have submit button as an optional option outside the Address component. My goal is validation message should not show until Submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. move validator to parent component
2. pass validatorMessage useState var to Address component
3. call the validator by the click of submit button

Now the message is managed in the parent component and you control when the submit button displays it.

Comment: But the validationMessage need to be in Address component. Will I be able to do that?

Comment: yes, you pass a variable (with useState) and once he clicks - the validator change the message var and the address will be notified for this change and display the message

Comment: @iceCream is it helped you?
if so mark the answer as 'answered' please

Comment: Yes, It helps. I am still thinking about how I call validator in submit button. My App (parent) suppose to have no prop.

Comment: App doesn't need to have a prop, only state, and send that var state as a prop to Address

Comment: Which value I should I set inside setValidate in the useState of parent?

Comment: The validateMessage inside Address was trigger before I hit Submit.

Comment: to solve that you have to check if the value of the validator is not empty, if so, display nothing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to consider a different approach: there is no need to manually implement validation, we can use the browser built-in validation feature:

https://medium.com/p/491327f985d0

Essentially I use standard HTML mark-up and properties.
Implementation example:

```
export default function App() {
  const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
    console.log(Object.fromEntries(data.entries()));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <h2>A simple form</h2>
        <TextInput label="Name:" id="name" name="name" required />
        <TextInput
          label="Email:"
          id="email"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          required
        />
        <TextInput label="Address:" id="address" name="address" />
        <TextInput
          label="Tel:"
          id="tel"
          name="tel"
          type="tel"
          pattern="((\+44(\s\(0\)\s|\s0\s|\s)?)|0)7\d{3}(\s)?\d{6}" // don't rely on this
        />

        <button>Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Form component itself is very simple:

```
    <form
      action={action}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      noValidate
      className={style.form}
    >
      <div className={style.wrapper}>{children}</div>
    </form>
```

It sets the `noValidate` attribute to prevent the default error notification to pop up.

The input boxes are wrapped in the `form` element.
The form element has an onSubmit event handler: it gets triggered when user clicks on the submit button OR when the user hit `return` using the keyboard.

At that point we use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent default form submission and handle it manually.

Comment: The article looks good, but on Stack Overflow we prefer at least the main part of some content to appear in the body of an answer itself. Could you edit your post to add that? (We call the above a "link only answer" and it may be at risk of deletion. If it is deleted don't worry about it, it can be undeleted after editing).

Comment: You've posted 10 answers that mostly seem like an excuse to link to this article. It feels a little spammy

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to spam.
I am replying to people asking the same question and the answer looks necessarily the same :)

Comment: Here is a [Meta post on duplicate answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315293/answering-borderline-duplicate-questions) - the short answer is it is discouraged. See the sidebar on that site too - plenty of reading material there. For your various answers today, it is possible that we need to put some of those on hold, because they are duplicates of each other.

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.